# Count unique symbols except white space

Tags: c#

How to add function to the program logic to output all symbols except space?

```
string text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(text[i]))
    {
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(text[i]))
        {
            dic.Add(text[i], text.Count(x => x == text[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could, please, you provide some *examples*?

Comment: "Output all symbols except [white] spaces": `string result = string.Concat(text.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));` e.g. `"bla bla\tbla" -> "blablabla"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get count of Unique chars in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322070/how-to-get-count-of-unique-chars-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to remove spaces, you can try something like this:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Replace(" ", "");
```

Or if you are dealing with tabs and not spaces:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Replace("\t", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using *Linq* when *querying*.

If you want to "output all symbols except [white] space[s]":

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string result = string.Concat(text.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

If you want to "count unique symbols except white spaces" and materialize the result as a dictionary:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  var dic = text
    .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
             string input = Console.ReadLine();

             var chars = input.ToCharArray();

             var uniqueChars = chars.Where(i=>i!= ' ').Distinct();

             var dictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();

             foreach(var ch in uniqueChars)
                      dictionary.Add(ch ,chars.Where(i => i == ch).Count());

             foreach(var keyValue in dictionary)
                      Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue.Key} : {keyValue.Value}");


         }
    }
```

It works for me:
saeed bolhasani
s : 2
a : 3
e : 2
d : 1
b : 1
o : 1
l : 1
h : 1
n : 1
i : 1